# Can you determine stack depth in C?

Tags: c, stack, printf, size

I was wondering if there is a function in C (let's dub it *int get_stack_depth()*), which returns the amount of functions currently being executed on the stack. For example:

```
int foo(){
    return get_stack_depth();
}

int bar2(){
    return get_stack_depth();
}

int bar1(){
    return bar2();
}

int bar(){
    return bar1();
}

int main(){
    get_stack_depth();      // = 0
    foo();                  // = 1
    bar();                  // = 3
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to use it for debugging info, where each printf would contain get_stack_depth() indents to increase readability. If this is compiler dependent, or anything-else dependent, I take all the constraints; right now I wonder whether this is supported at least somewhere.

EDIT: The answer at the suggested duplicate didn't help me at all, as the accepted answer here suggests, you cannot determine how many functions are on the stack based purely upon the size of the stack; the information is simply not there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find stack depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944372/how-to-find-stack-depth)

Comment: You can declare a file scope variable visible from all functions you define, and increase it upon function entry and decrease it just before returning from the function, for each function you define. That is an ugly solution but I don't think it can be done in a portable manner other than that.

Comment: You can see what glibc makes available to you [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html); there is no interface which tells you how deep the stack is, exactly, but if you have an upper limit `backtrace` will report how many slots up to the limit are in use. Note that not all function calls use stack frames, as indicated by the documentation.

Comment: @rici thank you for the link, I will definitely try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [backtrace()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html)?
for example:

```
#include <execinfo.h>
unsighed int getDepth(){
    const unsigned int max_depth = 200;
    void* buffer[max_depth];
    return backtrace(buffer, max_depth)-5;
}
```

The `-5` is there because there are some functions above `main` (added by the libc) that I want to ignore. However, if you want to calculate that automatically, change my function to

```
int get_stack_depth(int set_caller_as_root){
    static int root_depth = 0;

    if (set_caller_as_root){
        root_depth = get_stack_depth(0) - 1;
    }

    const int max_depth = 200;
    void* buffer[max_depth];
    return backtrace(buffer, max_depth) - root_depth;
}
```

and update your code to

```
int foo(){
    return get_stack_depth(0);
}

int bar2(){
    return get_stack_depth(0);
}

int bar1(){
    return bar2();
}

int bar(){
    return bar1();
}

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", get_stack_depth(1));     // = 0
    printf("%d\n", foo());                  // = 1
    printf("%d\n", bar());                  // = 3
    return 0;
}
```

which yields the correct, expected results.

Note that `execinfo.h` is not installed on windows 10 by default (it is on linux).

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. The question is outdated, but this is definitely the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

The exact mechanics of the stack in C are implementation-specific, so there is no single, correct, standard way to find the depth of the stack. There are some methods to simulate this behavior, though.

1. Use a counter. Define a global `unsigned depth`, and in each function in which you care about the depth of the stack, inject `depth++` at the beginning and `depth--` at the end. This is obviously the more tedious method, and it's prone to a lot of frustrating issues if an increment or decrement is left off.
2. Check the stack pointer. On x86 systems (virtually every desktop & laptop device), the stack grows downward, meaning that entering a function call will decrease the value of the stack pointer. In many cases (but not all, e.g. when optimization is enabled) the stack pointer register, `%rsp`, points to the "top" of the current function's stack frame. A rather hacky way to fetch this value is to assign it to a variable: `register uint64_t rsp asm ("rsp");`. The lower the value, the greater the depth on the stack.

   Unfortunately, the size of the decrement between function calls depends on how large the stack frame for that function is—if one function declares a large array as a local variable, then the stack pointer will be much lower for functions it calls, since more space is consumed by the array.

Ultimately the only reliable way I know of to find an accurate backtrace of function calls is to run the program in a debugger such as `gdb` and issue the `backtrace` command, which will print the current call stack. This kind of support just doesn't seem to be available to the program when it is run independent of any debugger.

Comment: Alright, seems like counter it is. Thanks for the clarification.